# Auto added primary key trying to insert the value of NULL

Tags: sql-server, django, django-models, windows-authentication

I have a Django site, and am using windows auth for it. When I try to logon as a new user it gives the error `Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'id', table 'table.auth_user'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails`. One other thing to mention is that that I have a separate db for my Auth (but the AuthDB is the default one).

models.py

```
class AuthUser(models.Model):
    password = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    last_login = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    is_superuser = models.BooleanField()
    username = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=150)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=254)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField()
    is_active = models.BooleanField()
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField()

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'auth_user'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username
```

In settings.py

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'sql_server.pyodbc',
        'NAME': 'AuthDB',
        'HOST': 'MyHost',
        'USER': '',
        'PASSWORD': '',
        'OPTIONS': {
            'driver':"ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server", 
            },
        'CONN_MAX_AGE': 60,
    },
```

I am not sure why django is trying to insert the value of NULL into the the auto added primary key id. Maybe I am missing something? Does anyone have any idea why? 
Thanks for the help!

Comment: have you changed the AUTH_USER_MODEL in your settings.py ??

Comment: My settings.py doesn't have an AUTH_USER_MODEL section

Comment: actually you are trying to create a new user system and overriding the user system of django auth ?

Comment: My site uses windows auth, so like if you log in on a windows account, (with credentials) then you can get on my site.